# Output an image

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output

Interestingly, although there are challenges that work with images, there is no challenge to simply output an image. This is that challenge

Goal: output an image in the shortest possible code.

Output: Any image output is accepted. Files would be preferable, but most any non-character on the screen will function as an image. An example of this is matplotlib output.

For languages that do not support file saving or direct image output, it is acceptable to output what would be the image file's content to any other kind of output. If a language supports saving to a file, this is not an option.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf); the shortest code that can accomplish the task will win.

Comment: Does a single pixel qualify?

Comment: What *is* an image? Anything non-text on the screen? An image *file* in any format? The contents of an image file outputted or returned?

Comment: @Somebody Yes, that is intended.

Comment: @Adám An image file in any format, unless a language has image output in another way.

Comment: What do you think about @Stef's comment on my answer? https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/267423/output-an-image/267425?noredirect=1#comment582467_267425 Does printing the contents of an image file to stdout qualify?

Comment: As of the last edit to this question, no, that would not count.

Answer (score 10):

## MATLAB, 3 bytes

```
spy
```

Displays the following image in a figure window.

Tested on Matlab R2017b and R2023b. Very old Matlab versions produced a different image.

[image]

### Explanation

From the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spy.html):

> `spy(S)` plots the sparsity pattern of matrix `S`. Nonzero values are colored while zero values are white. The plot displays the number of nonzeros in the matrix, `nz = nnz(S)`.

When called without input arguments, `spy` uses a default image. This is not documented, but it is [well known](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/articles/spy-easter-egg-take-2).

Answer (score 9):

## [Pyxplot](http://pyxplot.org.uk), 1 byte

```
p
```

`p` is an abbreviation for the `plot` command. When `p` is called as a bare keyword in the default environment, the file `pyxplot.eps` is created in the working directory, showing the default plot axes.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

## PICO-8, 5 bytes

```
spr()
```

Displays sprite 0 at (0,0). Sprite 0 is, conveniently enough, the only sprite that's not empty by default.

[image: A PICO-8 terminal with a graphic displayed.]

Answer (score 5):

## Google Sheets, 17 bytes

```
=sparkline({1;0})
```

Inserts a diagonal line in the formula cell. See [sparkline()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093289).

Multi-cell image with Unicode: (**13 bytes**)

```
=cursorpark()
```

[image: cursorpark]

The function is undocumented.

Comment: I've never seen this before.  Very nice!

Comment: TIL: cursorpark is a spot where you can park your cursor to not annoy others: https://www.reddit.com/r/BrandNewSentence/comments/oxk523/cursor_parking_lot/

Answer (score 5):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator) (or any graphing calculator really), 0 bytes

Ok this might be bending the rules quite a bit, but the output is the graph on the right (albeit empty, but still with axis lines and such) upon loading the Desmos Graphing Calculator website. Please say so if this isn't allowed; I will promptly delete this answer if that is the case.

Comment: This definitely bends the rules. I'm going to say it doesn't count because the program isn't actually drawing anything. The axes and grid are really just background. One character would work, however: x. P.S. please don't delete this answer

Comment: It's self-contradictory to say "it doesn't count" and "please don't delete this answer" - the community consensus has long been that answers that don't count have to be deleted.

Answer (score 4):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org/), <s>9</s> 6 bytes ([SBCS](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=0_7_1__IyBTaW5nbGUtYnl0ZSBjaGFyYWN0ZXIgZW5jb2RpbmcgZm9yIFVpdWEgMC44LjAKIyBXcml0dGVuIGhhc3RpbHkgYnkgVG9ieSBCdXNpY2stV2FybmVyLCBAVGJ3IG9uIFN0YWNrIEV4Y2hhbmdlCiMgMjcgRGVjZW1iZXIgMjAyMwojIEFQTCdzICLijbUiIGlzIHVzZWQgYXMgYSBwbGFjZWhvbGRlci4KCkNPTlRST0wg4oaQICJcMOKNteKNteKNteKNteKNteKNteKNteKNteKNtVxu4o214o21XHLijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbXijbUiClBSSU5UQUJMRSDihpAgIiAhXCIjJCUmJygpKissLS4vMDEyMzQ1Njc4OTo7PD0-P0BBQkNERUZHSElKS0xNTk9QUVJTVFVWV1hZWltcXF1eX2BhYmNkZWZnaGlqa2xtbm9wcXJzdHV2d3h5ent8fX7ijbUiClVJVUEg4oaQICLiiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYXiiaDiiaTiiaXDl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4oSC4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmtwqTii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHii5XiiY3iip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_imIfihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipfiiKfiiLXiiaHiip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziipDii4XiipniiKnCsOKMheKNnOKKg-KqvuKKk-KLlOKNouKsmuKNo-KNpOKGrOKGq-Kags63z4DPhOKInuK4ruKGkOKVreKUgOKVt-KVr-KfpuKfp-KMnOKMn-KVk-KVn-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))

Outputs an actual image.

```
↯.⊂.30
```

`30`  put the number 30 on the stack (numeric arrays of size 30×30+ output as images)

`.` duplicate (now we have two 30s on the stack)

`⊂` join (into single array, leaving `[30,30]` on the stack)

`.` duplicate (now we have two `[30,30]`s on the stack)

`↯` reshape (now we have a 30×30 array of 30s on the stack)

[Try it on uiua.org](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_6_1__4oavLuKKgi4zMA==)

Comment: You can save 1 byte (but +1 character) by using `30_30` instead of `⊂.30`. Unfortunately, Uiua's `⊂` takes up 3 bytes. Probably worth keeping both solutions should someone create a better byte encoding for Uiua.

Comment: `[.30]` also works.

Comment: @Tbw Thanks, added.

Comment: I made a Uiua [SBCS](http://tinyurl.com/UiuaSBCS), so you can stick with the shorter solution at only 6 bytes.

Comment: @Tbw Thanks, updated.

Answer (score 4):

## [Mathematica (Notebook interface)](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/), 3 bytes

```
Red
```

In recent versions of Mathematica (I don't remember since when), color objects are displayed as colored boxes in the notebook interface.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## HTML (Stack Snippet), 9 bytes

```html
<img src=
```

Displays the "broken image" icon. Abuses the fact that the stack snippet wraps the HTML input inside a template HTML document, so what ends being parsed is `<img src=<script type="text/javascript">` (thanks @Kaiido).

Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge:
[image: image of the chrome and edge "broken image" icon]

Firefox:
[image: image of the firefox "broken image" icon]

## HTML, 11 bytes

```html
<img src=/>
```

Same thing but works outside of stack snippets.

Comment: This doesn't really work. The StackSnippet will wrap your HTML input inside a template html, so what ends being parsed is `<img src="script" type="text/javascript">`.  An HTML parser won't recognize just `<img src=` as an `<img>` tag, you need the closing `>`. Also, to show the "broken image" icon, it needs to have a non-empty `src` attribute. So the actual minimal is `<img src=.>`. https://super-attractive-libra.glitch.me But there is still a catch, it must be served from a non-opaque origin, otherwise the browser won't do the relative request and still no broken-icon.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, 18 bytes

```
import antigravity
```

Comment: I think you should at the very least do `with open('f.pbm', 'w') as f: print("P1 1 1 1", file=f)` in order for the pbm solution to qualify. The OP says either output a file or display an image on-screen; `print("P1 1 1 1")` does neither, it just outputs 9 characters. The antigravity option is great though.

Comment: @Stef good point; I asked the OP. If they say printing doesn't count, then I'll just remove the first part and leave the antigravity one, because `open('f.pbm','w').write("P1 1 1 1")` is longer.

Comment: Well, if it doesn't count then many current solutions are invalidated. It functions as a valid option.

Comment: @Jakav Which "Many current solutions" would be invalidated? I can see only this python answer and [the brainfuck answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/267430/96480). Other solutions either really display an image on screen, or save an image file. And brainfuck cannot save image files nor display images, so it's fair to tolerate the brainfuck answer. But python can both save images and display images, so printing 9 characters to screen really is not a correct solution!

Comment: I see 4 answers which use the PBM format and simply output it, which is "many current solutions". However, only two of those would be affected by this change. I'll revise the challenge.

Comment: *actually just this one, my mistake

Answer (score 3):

## [QBasic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QBasic), 15 bytes

```
SCREEN 9
DRAW"D
```

Starting in the middle of the screen, draw a short vertical line in the default white foreground color. Output when run on [Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/msdos_qbasic_megapack):

[image: A black screen with a tiny white line in the middle and the text "Press any key to continue" at the bottom]

Comment: Upvoted for QBasic, woop woop!

Answer (score 3):

## HTML, 8 bytes

Outputs a transparent-black canvas image. On most browsers you can right-click "Save image as..." on it.

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid } /* not required */
```

```html
<canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

## (ba)sh: 20 bytes

Black pixel:

```
echo P1 1 1 1 >i.pbm
```

White pixel:

```
echo P1 1 1 0 >i.pbm
```

Utilizes the rather rarely-used PBM format. PPM is it's bigger brother, supporting RGB.
Red pixel (more bytes):

```
echo P3 1 1 1 1 0 0 >i.pbm
```

Very useful protocol when piping images from stdout of one program to stdin of another, not so much for anything else. But it's still an image...

#### Phylosophical answer: Browser: 1 byte

```
$
```

It's rendered from a font file onto your screen. It's a shape consisting of multiple bytes. Therefore, it's an image?

Comment: Love the philosophical answer.

Comment: If you're running bash on Mac OS X>=10.2 you can do `screencapture a.png` which is only 19 bytes

Comment: You can save a byte on each Bash answer by doing `echo>i.pbm P1 1 1 1` etc.

Answer (score 1):

## [PBM](https://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pbm.html), 8 bytes

```
P1 1 1 1
```

Or, if you don't consider an image file as a valid submission, any program that outputs the bytes above.

Comment: I would prefer not to consider an image file itself a valid submission, as although it could technically be "run" by an image viewer, it doesn't really output an image; it is the image.

Comment: @Jakav Then it can simply claim the language as [Text](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Text), and nothing would be changed.

Comment: I just want to say I approve, this is the answer I was going to write when I saw the question.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 60 bytes

```
-[+>++[++<]>]>.>>-[-[-<]>>+<]>->>-[<+>-----]<--.<.>.<.>.<.>.
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70yqSgxMy-tNDl7wYKlpSVpuhY3bXSjte20taO1tW1i7WLt9OzsdKOBEMixA4nogvg22na6IBBro6urZ6NnB8cQM6BGwYwEAA)

Outputs the same PBM image of [these](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/267425/73593) [answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/267424/73593).

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (browser), <s>58</s> 47 bytes

```js
f=

_=>document.createElement("canvas").toDataURL()

;document.write(`<a href="${f()}">Right-click to download</a>`)
```

Outputs a transparent 300×150 rectangle. Edit: Saved 11 bytes thanks to @Kaiido.

Comment: It's actually transparent, not white. And no need for the mime type, png is the default. Also `toBlob()` is shorter.

Comment: And if going the `toBlob()` road, then `new OffscreenCanvas(1,1).convertToBlob()` is one byte shorter.

Comment: @Kaiido Although those functions don't actually return the image as such, which currently doesn't appear to be an allowed output method.

Comment: `dataURL()` either. It outputs a string, which is one of the representations of a binary file. A `Blob` object is another. If a data: URL is a valid return value, I don't see why a `Blob` wouldn't be.

Comment: @Kaiido `toBlob` doesn't actually *return* the blob though...

Comment: `convertToBlob` returns a Promise that does resolve with the Blob, isn't it ok to just have to `await` a return value? And you could pass a callback to `f`: https://jsfiddle.net/32yc5net/

Comment: @Kaiido Actually yes a Promise would be acceptable, but at this point I can't be bothered to rewrite my snippet to actually display the result.

Comment: Maybe https://jsfiddle.net/2u4atsj3/1/ ?

Answer (score 1):

## Windows, 1 keystroke

PrintScreen

Output to clipboard

Comment: That relies on the `Use the PrtScn button to open screen snipping` setting in Settings>Ease of Access>Interaction>Keyboard being set to Off.

Comment: In Windows 10 at least.
I'm not sure whether that setting is on or off by default.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, 1 byte

```
DispGraph
```

Displays the graph screen.

Comment: Is this really 1 byte? It's 9 in the format it is shown here.

Comment: @Jakav [TI-BASIC is tokenized](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4764). `e` is 2 bytes while `LinReg(ax+b)` is 1 byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 41 bytes

```cs
new System.Drawing.Bitmap(9,9).Save("p");
```

Creates a transparent 9x9 pixel PNG image.

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 3 bytes

```
1XG
```

[Try it at MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=1XG&inputs=&version=22.8.0)

Draws a plot of the point (1,1):

[image: The MATL online output window, showing axes and a point at coordinates (1,1)]

`XG` is the `plot` builtin. I'm not 100% sure why passing it a real number \$N\$ plots the point \$(1,N)\$, but it works.